# Problem with sscanf() doesn't read every 0 that is in char array

Tags: c++, scanf, arduino-ide

I need to extract numbers from my char array, it stores value in format hh:mm(example 20:20)
I tried using sscanf function to extract hh into hour variable and mm to minute  variable.
It is working nicely until the time is something like 0number:0number or if it is 00:00 ..It only returns the number without the 0 or only one 0. Is it possible that when it reads the first 0 it takes it as something else ,not the part of the array value? Thank you for any answer.

```
char time[15]; ///where I store the time value 
Serial.println(time); //prints nicely something like 02:02
int hour;
int minute;

sscanf(incas,"%02d:%02d",&hour,&minute); 
Serial.println(hour);  ///prints 2
Serial.println(minute); ///prints 2
```

Comment: You're reading an integer, there's no such number as 01, it's 1. The problem is with your print, because you print the number and expect to print 01 instead of 1. :)

Comment: ooh okay thank you I did't actually think of it this way,it makes sense :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `int` has no clue about leading zeroes. `0000000000000123 == 123`. If you want leading zeroes, you'll have to format it yourself.

Example converting `hour` and `minute` back to a `char` array:

```
char out[15];
sprintf(out, "%02d:%02d", hour, minute);
Serial.println(out);
```

Comment: Thank you I understand now :)

Comment: Technically depending on context, 0000000000000123 != 123, because 0000000000000123 is an octal literal :) Not with %d though.

Comment: @eerorika :schsss... :-D

Answer (score 1):

The problem doesn't lie with your call to `sscanf` but with the one to `println`. Try this:

```cpp
char time[15]; ///where I store the time value 
Serial.println(time); //prints nicely something like 02:02
int hour;
int minute;

sscanf(incas,"%02d:%02d",&hour,&minute); 
char strBuf[3];
sprintf(strBuf, "%02d", hour);//hour is an int, so you need to pad with leading 0's
Serial.println(strBuf);  ///prints 2
sprintf(strBuf, "%02d", minute);
Serial.println(strBuf); ///prints 2
```

Comment: Yes thank you,my main issue wasn't actually to print it out but I wanted to work with that value..but now when I think of it I was really stupid and actually did't need those zeros :D next time I must think harder and different about my problems